# rpc error while setting up tezos-client

Tags: tezos-client

`tezos-client --endpoint https://edonet-tezos.giganode.io/ config update` throws error

[image]

```
  Failed to acquire the protocol version from the node
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: https://edonet-tezos.giganode.io//chains/main/blocks/head/protocols
     - error: Unable to connect to the node: "TLS to non-TCP currently unsupported: host=edonet-tezos.giganode.io endp=(Unknown "name resolution failed")"
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Edonet is an old test network. It does not exist anymore.

Try `tezos-client -E https://testnet-tezos.giganode.io`

**Or**

`tezos-client -E https://ithacanet.visualtez.com`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to participate in the current testing network, follow the instructions here: https://teztnets.xyz/ithacanet-about